# How to switch between USB Dongle and Wifi connection in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, internet, usb-modem, 3g, wifi-direct

I have installed Ubuntu 20 server in my Raspberry pi board which I have connected with Wifi. I have installed a 3G Dongle to the ubuntu server. Now the 3G Dongle connection is also working fine. Right now, what I need to do is When the Wifi is down it should automatically connect to 3G Dongle and once the Wifi is back it should connect to the Wifi again.

I don't have a clue on how to do this do we need to write any script to switch the connection between two automatically. Could anyone pls help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could adapt https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic  You'll have to add the "repeatedly see if WiFi came up (when on 3G)" part yourself.

Comment: Can you pls give me some more information on it.Do i need to simply add the net-o-matic.conf file (If so in which path i need to add it)